# The commutator of any two transpositions in $S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Given any two transpositions $(i,j),(k,l) \in S_n$ such that $i,j,k,l$ are all distinct, is it true that: 
$[(i,j),(k,l)]=(i,j)(k,l)(i,j)(k,l)=[(i,j)(k,l)][(i,j)(k,l)]=\text{identity}$?
I would appreciate your observation.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

1) Disjoint cycles permute: $\;(ij)(kl)=(kl)(ij)\;$ , for pairwise different $\;i,j,k,l\;$

2)$\; (ij)^{-1}=(ij)\;$

Comment: Does that mean I was wrong?

Comment: No, it means that the question you asked has "yes" as answer, and this follows at once from the hints above.

Comment: Oh thank you. 
I did take those hints into consideration writing it.

Comment: But then why did you aks the question? Do you have any doubt about the hints' truth or how to apply them to your question? Because I think that applying them the answer is immediate by the definition of "commutator of two elements in a group".

Comment: It is the result of being insufficiently familiar with the permutation group of a n-elements set... I never was completely sure that (1,2)*(3,4), for example, is to be one permutation... Now you made it unequivocally clear.

Comment: @Meitar I see. Glad I could help.